# Error while Generate Signed APK after integrating Firebase Crashlytics

Tags: android, gradle, crashlytics

I have followed official docs to integrate firebase crashlytis. 
https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/get-started

it is working fine for debug build & i am getting crashes in console also, but I am getting below error while generating signed APK.

```
Warning:com.twitter.sdk.android.core.internal.scribe.ScribeFilesSender$ConfigRequestInterceptor: can't find referenced method 'java.lang.String getDeviceUUID()' in program class io.fabric.sdk.android.services.common.IdManager
Information:See complete output in console
Warning:there were 1 unresolved references to program class members.
Information:3 warnings
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesAndResourcesWithProguardForLivedemoRelease'.
> Job failed, see logs for details
Information:1 error
Information:BUILD FAILED in 10s
Warning:Exception while processing task java.io.IOException: Please correct the above warnings first.
```

app level build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'


android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    buildToolsVersion "27.0.3"
    defaultConfig {
       ----
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 5885
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
        multiDexEnabled true
        buildConfigField 'boolean', 'DIALER_WITH_RECENT', 'false'
    }
    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            debuggable false
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }


    flavorDimensions "prod"
    productFlavors {
        prod {
            dimension "prod"
            .....
        }
        livedemo {
            dimension "prod"
            .....
        }
        stage {
            dimension "prod"
            .....
        }
        stage2 {
            dimension "prod"
           ....
        }
    }
}


dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    /*androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })*/
    //bluetooth
    //compile 'com.estimote:sdk:0.11.1@aar'//Beacon-code
    /*androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-contrib:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v4'
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'design'
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'recyclerview-v7'
    }*/
    //compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    /*compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:10.0.1'*/
    //facebook login
    //twitter login
    implementation('com.twitter.sdk.android:twitter-core:1.6.6@aar') {
        transitive = true
    }
    implementation('com.twitter.sdk.android:twitter:1.13.1@aar') {
        transitive = true
    }
    implementation project(':libraryHashTag')
    implementation files('libs/SQLiteStudioRemote.jar')

    implementation project(':SwipeMenuLibCustom')

    implementation files('libs/jtar-1.1.jar')
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.3.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.3.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.9.1'
    implementation 'com.github.JakeWharton:ViewPagerIndicator:2.4.1'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.5.0'
    implementation 'com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.6.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-safetynet:11.8.0'
    implementation 'com.github.clans:fab:1.6.4'
    implementation 'org.ocpsoft.prettytime:prettytime:4.0.1.Final'
    implementation 'com.github.chrisbanes:PhotoView:2.1.3'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:11.8.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.8.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:11.8.0'
    implementation 'com.github.kenglxn.QRGen:android:2.4.0'
    implementation 'com.journeyapps:zxing-android-embedded:3.5.0'
    implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.28.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:11.8.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.8.0'
    implementation 'com.splitwise:tokenautocomplete:2.0.8'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.8.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:11.8.0'
    implementation 'com.github.castorflex.smoothprogressbar:library:1.1.0'

    /*For Crashlytics*/
    releaseImplementation('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.9.1@aar') {
        transitive = true
    }
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.8.0'

    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}


apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'
```

Proguard rules file

```
# Add project specific ProGuard rules here.
# By default, the flags in this file are appended to flags specified
# in D:\Android\sdk/tools/proguard/proguard-android.txt
# You can edit the include path and order by changing the proguardFiles
# directive in build.gradle.
#
# For more details, see
#   http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/proguard.html

# Add any project specific keep options here:

# If your project uses WebView with JS, uncomment the following
# and specify the fully qualified class name to the JavaScript interface
# class:
#-keepclassmembers class fqcn.of.javascript.interface.for.webview {
#   public *;
#}
-dontwarn javax.annotation.**
-dontwarn com.squareup.okhttp3.**
-keep class com.squareup.okhttp3.** { *; }
-keep interface com.squareup.okhttp3.* { *; }
-dontwarn javax.annotation.Nullable
-dontwarn javax.annotation.ParametersAreNonnullByDefault
-dontwarn javax.annotation.GuardedBy
-keep public class * implements com.bumptech.glide.module.GlideModule
-keep public enum com.bumptech.glide.load.resource.bitmap.ImageHeaderParser$** {
  **[] $VALUES;
  public *;
}
-dontwarn okio.**
-dontwarn org.apache.lang.**
-dontwarn org.joda.time.**
-dontwarn org.w3c.dom.**
-dontwarn com.viewpagerindicator.**
-keep class android.support.v4.** { *; }
-dontnote android.support.v4.**
-dontwarn retrofit2.Platform$Java8
-keep class android.support.v4.app.** { *; }
-keep interface android.support.v4.app.** { *; }
-keep class android.support.v7.app.** { *; }
-keep interface android.support.v7.app.** { *; }
-keep class android.support.v7.widget.SearchView { *; }
-keep class org.ocpsoft.prettytime.**

-keep class com.estimote.sdk.* { *; }
-keep interface com.estimote.sdk.* { *; }
-dontwarn com.estimote.sdk.**

-dontwarn com.beloo.widget.chipslayoutmanager.Orientation
-keep class com.beloo.widget.chipslayoutmanager.* { *; }
-keep class com.beloo.widget.chipslayoutmanager.** { *; }
-keep class com.beloo.widget.chipslayoutmanager.*$* { *; }
-keep class RestrictTo.*
-keep class RestrictTo.**
-keep class RestrictTo.*$*

-keep class org.ocpsoft.prettytime.i18n.**

-keepclassmembers class android.support.design.internal.BottomNavigationMenuView {
    boolean mShiftingMode;
}


-keep class com.crashlytics.** { *; }
-dontwarn com.crashlytics.**
-keepattributes SourceFile,LineNumberTable
-keep public class * extends java.lang.Exception


#-renamesourcefileattribute SourceFile
#-keepattributes SourceFile,LineNumberTable

#-printmapping mapping.txt

#-keepresourcexmlelements manifest/application/meta-data@value=GlideModule
```

Comment: Pl. post the build gradle and progurad files as well.

Comment: @AnoopM please check added build.gradle

Comment: I found nothing wrong with your gradle, you may post your pro-guard file also.

Comment: @AnoopM please check edited question

Comment: Can you try this-

`-keepclassmembernames class * { 
    java.lang.Class class$(java.lang.String); 
    java.lang.Class class$(java.lang.String, boolean); 
} 
`

Comment: Sorry, its not working. same error appear

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mike from Fabric here. You're using versions of Twitter's SDK that are no longer supported on Fabric. Specifically:

```
//twitter login
implementation('com.twitter.sdk.android:twitter-core:1.6.6@aar') {
    transitive = true
}
implementation('com.twitter.sdk.android:twitter:1.13.1@aar') {
    transitive = true
}
```

You should update to [Twitter's](https://github.com/twitter/twitter-kit-android/wiki/Getting-Started) new SDK which is on version 3.x.

Answer (score 1):

To skip running ProGuard on Crashlytics, just add the following to your ProGuard config file.

```
-keep class com.crashlytics.** { *; }
-dontwarn com.crashlytics.**
```

Next, in order to provide the most meaningful crash reports, add the following line to your configuration file:

```
-keepattributes SourceFile,LineNumberTable
```

Crashlytics will still function without this rule, but your crash reports will not include proper file names or line numbers.

If you are using custom exceptions, add this line so that custom exception types are skipped during obfuscation:

```
-keep public class * extends java.lang.Exception
```